# Write/Read from property list on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I know there are thousands of tutorials on the topic however I don't get it to work.
What I am trying to do is to read an value from a plist file. Then I check whether or not I have to update the value. This part is ok. However I don't managed to get the value saved in plist file. I have a Settings.Bundle and it is where I am trying to read/store.

It is just a simple string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will give you a NSDictionary with your settings bundle information.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
```

If there are any other generic plist you would like to read you can easily load them into a NSDictionary using

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
//or
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
```

Also I would like to add for reading and saving values I would recommend doing that in the NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
id anObj = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"myKey"];
//Modify anObj
...
[userDefaults setObject:anObj forKey:@"myKey"];
[userDefaults synchronize];//Save immediately if you choose
```

Comment: So it is possible to save such simple values?

Comment: Yes you can save any combination of the following NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify files/folders present in your app bundle (such as Settings.bundle.) They are read-only.

Comment: So what would be the best way of storing a number then? Write a txt file to documents folder?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults`. Settings.bundle defines the *interface* for your app's settings. The actual values of those settings are manipulated via the `NSUserDefaults` class.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. All I want is to read and store a URL.  Is it possible to read/write from the app to the settings.bundle or a plist file? Or are there other solutions?

Comment: **Use `NSUserDefaults` to store your application settings and preferences.**